# How should we tag questions about Ms. Marvel (Kamala Khan)?

Tags: discussion, tags

I want to ask a question about the Marvel character Ms. Marvel (Kamala Khan), but I don't know how it should be tagged.

[Multiple characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ms._Marvel) have been called Ms. Marvel in the comics. It originally referred to Carol Danvers, but she's been known as [captain-marvel](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/captain-marvel) since 2012. Kamala Khan has been the new Ms. Marvel since her series started in 2014.

Should questions about Kamala Khan be tagged as:

- [ms-marvel](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ms-marvel)
- [kamala-khan](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kamala-khan)
- [ms-marvel-kamala-khan](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ms-marvel-kamala-khan)

Comment: As a rule, there's no need to complicate matters if there isn't a problem and currently  there's no tag for the character(s) so no problem. So just go ahead and use the most sensible one.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot Isn't this question asking "Which of these options is the most sensible one"?

Comment: @user568458 Essentially yes but the OP seems to know [[tag:ms-marvel]] is probably the best route. They're' just asking if we need to be more specific as the tag could relate to more characters. My comment is simply saying as we have no need for tags on the other characters yet it doesn't really matter about being more specific.

Answer (score 9):

[captain-marvel](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/captain-marvel) is used for Carol Danvers already so there shouldn't be any confusion that [ms-marvel](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ms-marvel) will be about Kamala Khan. Considering the upcoming series *Ms. Marvel* is going to feature Kamala as Ms. Marvel and Kamala has been that character for years I don't see the need to complicate matters. Just use [ms-marvel](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ms-marvel) for questions about the character.

To avoid any confusion with the series when that comes out we can just use the year suffix, [ms-marvel-year](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ms-marvel-year), that is common practice.

Comment: So you’re saying that anybody who wants to ask a question about Carol Danvers while she had the title of “Ms. Marvel” (say, a question about her time on the Avengers in the 80s) should use the tag [captain-marvel]?

Comment: @Thunderforge I refer you to my comment on the question. Until that arises there’s no need to complicate matters. There’s been no problem yet so we don’t need to make it one.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot There is at least [one question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/4743/79413) about Carol Danvers as Ms. Marvel.

Comment: And, for completeness, the original Captain Marvel is now [tag:shazam]. [We're not talking about him](https://youtu.be/kTcRRaXV-fg?t=160).

Answer (score 2):

Considering that several characters, including one from Marvel's Distinguished Competition, have used the title "Captain Marvel", and Carol *herself* was known as Ms Marvel, I'd personally be in favor of using the "ms-marvel-kamala-khan" tag for proper distinction. It's little different than using the different tags for "powers" and "super-powers" or "special-abilities"; all cover basically the same topics and areas, but there is a higher level of specificity for clarity of the posters.

It makes things logically easier to differentiate, is my thoughts. and this way, if one uses the "ms-Marvel" tag, they can speak to **both** of these heroes without failing.