# Should [ms-marvel] be split since there's now a tag for the TV show?

Tags: discussion

Currently, the [ms-marvel](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ms-marvel) tag is written for the comic. I created a [ms-marvel-2022](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ms-marvel-2022) tag for my question about the show. Did I jump the gun in doing that? Is invoking the [marvel-cinematic-universe](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/marvel-cinematic-universe) tag alongside [ms-marvel](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ms-marvel) sufficient? Or should there be a tag for the comic, and one for the overall mythos? I'm kind of a splitter in general on this sort of a topic, favoring specialized tags, but I know that's not always what is right.

Comment: https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12669/how-should-we-tag-questions-about-ms-marvel-kamala-khan did suggest the [tag:ms-marvel-2022] setup for when the show was to come out.

Comment: Oh looks like two tags for the TV show have been created I thought there was already one. Bear with I’ll merge them.

Comment: [tag:ms-marvel] is for the character as a whole. We don’t really need character specific tags for each media; just use in conjunction with said media tag the question is about I.e. [tag:comics] or [tag:mcu].

Comment: Between them (after Carrot merged in [tag:ms.-marvel-2022]) there are only 8 questions.  That seems very few to require 2 separate tags.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot The main tag for the TV show should be [tag:ms.-marvel-2022] (with a period), to reflect the actual name of the TV show, "Ms. Marvel".  [tag:ms-marvel-2022] should be made a synonym to  [tag:ms.-marvel-2022].

Comment: @galacticninja A slightly incorrect tag name should be preferred over one that's a bit more difficult to find as evidenced by the second tag being created. Even with the synonym it's preferred to have it this way round in my opinion.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot "*one that's a bit more difficult to find*" That's where the tag synonymization comes in. The tag that is easier to find will redirect anyway to the correct tag name that better reflects the actual name of the TV show and character.

Comment: I'm still working out the fact that Ms. Marvel is no longer Carol Danvers, and that Captain Marvel is no longer Mar-Vell.

Comment: @Clockwork I think there's another Binary too.